# How to "Deploy" asp.net MVC 4 to Microsoft Server 2012 IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, windows-server-2012

I have asp.net MVC 4 application and i want to "send" it to Microsoft Server 2012 IIS7, so the site can be reached from internet.
How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the Web project in Visual Studio and then choose the `Publish ...` option from the context menu. Then follow the steps. You might also go through some of the detailed overviews if the publishing process such as [`this article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.