# Deploying MVC 4 with Razor on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, iis-7, web-deployment

I've created an MVC 4 project and am trying to deploy it on IIS 7. I've seen a lot of suggestions and tried some and had no luck. I'm very new to IIS so I need this explained as thoroughly as possible if someone can. I currently run my MVC application from localhost and then I add something like this to the end of the URL.

/data/filldata?name=...

So my first question is, how do I deploy the MVC website to IIS. My next question is, after deploying it, how do I run it? If I open a web browser, what should I put in the URL. My assumption is the new URL with the directory it's set up in and then that /data/filldata?name=... at the end. Keep in mind that I am a beginner in this so I'm slowly starting to learn how to use IIS. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616228/how-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc-4-to-microsoft-server-2012-iis7